# Full Background in the Site javascript

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

Hello I have a site from my homepage that load the Background image not the end of the site.

Im testing this in Google Chrome.

Here my Problem:

[image]
Here my Site:

http://www.behringer-mauch.de/Tischler_Hehmann/index.php?article_id=12

On the another site from the homepage that load die Background images to end of the site.

Example:

http://www.behringer-mauch.de/Tischler_Hehmann/index.php?article_id=7

I don't know what the problem :(

I hope someone can help me.

here is the javascript code:

```
    /*!
 * jQuery.BgSwitcher
 *
 * @version  0.4.2
 * @author   rewish <rewish.org@gmail.com>
 * @license  MIT License (https://github.com/rewish/jquery-bgswitcher/blob/master/LICENSE.md)
 * @link     https://github.com/rewish/jquery-bgswitcher
 */
(function($) {
    'use strict';

    var loadedImages = {},

        slice = Array.prototype.slice,
        toString = Object.prototype.toString,

        edges = ['Top', 'Right', 'Bottom', 'Left'],
        backgroundProperties = [
            'Attachment', 'Color', 'Image', 'Repeat',
            'Position', 'Size', 'Clip', 'Origin'
        ];

    $.fn.bgswitcher = function() {
        var args = arguments,
            instanceKey = BgSwitcher.keys.instance;

        return this.each(function() {
            var instance = $.data(this, instanceKey);

            if (!instance) {
                instance = new BgSwitcher(this);
                $.data(this, instanceKey, instance);
            }

            instance.dispatch.apply(instance, args);
        });
    };

    // Backward Compatibility
    $.fn.bgSwitcher = $.fn.bgswitcher;

    /**
     * BgSwitcher
     *
     * @param {HTMLElement} el
     * @constructor
     */
    function BgSwitcher(el) {
        this.$el = $(el);
        this.index = 0;
        this.config = $.extend({}, BgSwitcher.defaultConfig);

        this._setupBackgroundElement();
        this._listenToResize();
    }

    $.extend(BgSwitcher.prototype, {
        /**
         * Dispatch
         *
         * @param {string|Array} one
         */
        dispatch: function(one) {
            switch (toString.call(one)) {
                case '[object Object]':
                    this.setConfig(one);
                    break;
                case '[object String]':
                    this[one].apply(this, slice.call(arguments, 1));
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Error('Please specify a Object or String');
            }
        },

        /**
         * Set config
         *
         * @param {Object} config
         */
        setConfig: function(config) {
            this.config = $.extend(this.config, config);

            if (typeof this.config.random !== 'undefined') {
                this.config.shuffle = this.config.random;
            }

            this._prepare();
        },

        /**
         * Set images
         *
         * @param {Array} images
         */
        setImages: function(images) {
            this.imageList = new this.constructor.ImageList(images);

            if (this.config.shuffle) {
                this.imageList.shuffle();
            }
        },

        /**
         * Set switch handler
         *
         * @param {Function} fn
         */
        setSwitchHandler: function(fn) {
            this.switchHandler = $.proxy(fn, this);
        },

        /**
         * Default switch handler
         *
         * @param {string} type
         * @returns {Function}
         */
        getBuiltInSwitchHandler: function(type) {
            return this.constructor.switchHandlers[type || this.config.effect];
        },

        /**
         * Adjust rectangle
         */
        adjustRectangle: function() {
            var edge,
                i = 0,
                length = edges.length,
                offset = this.$el.position(),
                copiedStyles = {
                    top: offset.top,
                    left: offset.left,
                    width: this.$el.innerWidth(),
                    height: this.$el.innerHeight()
                };

            for (; i < length; i++) {
                edge = edges[i];
                copiedStyles['margin' + edge] = this.$el.css('margin' + edge);
                copiedStyles['border' + edge] = this.$el.css('border' + edge);
            }

            this.$bg.css(copiedStyles);
        },

        /**
         * Start switching
         */
        start: function() {
            if (!this._timerID) {
                this._timerID = setTimeout($.proxy(this, 'next'), this.config.interval);
            }
        },

        /**
         * Stop switching
         */
        stop: function() {
            if (this._timerID) {
                clearTimeout(this._timerID);
                this._timerID = null;
            }
        },

        /**
         * Toggle between start/stop
         */
        toggle: function() {
            if (this._timerID) {
                this.stop();
            } else {
                this.start();
            }
        },

        /**
         * Reset switching
         */
        reset: function() {
            this.index = 0;
            this._prepareSwitching();
        },

        /**
         * Go to next switching
         */
        next: function() {
            var max = this.imageList.count();

            if (!this.config.loop && this.index + 1 === max) {
                return;
            }

            if (++this.index === max) {
                this.index = 0;
            }

            this.switching();
        },

        /**
         * Go to previous switching
         */
        prev: function() {
            if (!this.config.loop && this.index === 0) {
                return;
            }

            if (--this.index === -1) {
                this.index = this.imageList.count() - 1;
            }

            this.switching();
        },

        /**
         * Select the switching at index
         *
         * @param {number} index
         */
        select: function(index) {
            if (index === -1) {
                index = this.imageList.count() - 1;
            }

            this.index = index;
            this.switching();
        },

        /**
         * Switching the background image
         */
        switching: function() {
            var started = !!this._timerID;

            if (started) {
                this.stop();
            }

            this._createSwitchableElement();
            this._prepareSwitching();
            this.switchHandler(this.$switchable);

            if (started) {
                this.start();
            }
        },

        /**
         * Destroy...
         */
        destroy: function() {
            this.stop();
            this._stopListeningToResize();

            if (this.$switchable) {
                this.$switchable.stop();
                this.$switchable.remove();
                this.$switchable = null;
            }

            if (this.$bg) {
                this.$bg.remove();
                this.$bg = null;
            }

            this.$el.removeAttr('style');
            this.$el.removeData(this.constructor.keys.instance);
            this.$el = null;
        },

        /**
         * Prepare
         */
        _prepare: function() {
            this.setImages(this.config.images);
            this.setSwitchHandler(this.getBuiltInSwitchHandler());
            this._prepareSwitching();

            if (this.config.start) {
                this.start();
            }
        },

        /**
         * Setup background element
         */
        _setupBackgroundElement: function() {
            this.$bg = $(document.createElement('div'));
            this.$bg.css({

                position: 'absolute',
                paddingBottom: '0px',
                backgroundattachment: 'fixed!important',
                zIndex: (parseInt(this.$el.css('zIndex'), 10) || 0) - 1,
                overflow: 'hidden'

            });

            this._copyBackgroundStyles();
            this.adjustRectangle();

            if (this.$el[0].tagName === 'BODY') {
                this.$el.prepend(this.$bg);
            } else {
                this.$el.before(this.$bg);
                this.$el.css('background', 'none');
            }
        },

        /**
         * Create switchable element
         */
        _createSwitchableElement: function() {
            if (this.$switchable) {
                this.$switchable.remove();
            }

            this.$switchable = this.$bg.clone();
            this.$switchable.css({top: 0, left: 0, margin: 0, border: 'none'});
            this.$switchable.appendTo(this.$bg);
        },

        /**
         * Copy background styles
         */
        _copyBackgroundStyles: function () {
            var prop,
                copiedStyle = {},
                length = backgroundProperties.length,
                i = 0;

            for (; i < length; i++) {
                prop = 'background' + backgroundProperties[i];
                copiedStyle[prop] = this.$el.css(prop);
            }

            this.$bg.css(copiedStyle);
        },

        /**
         * Listen to the resize event
         */
        _listenToResize: function() {
            var that = this;
            this._resizeHandler = function() {
                that.adjustRectangle();
            };
            $(window).on('resize', this._resizeHandler);
        },

        /**
         * Stop listening to the resize event
         */
        _stopListeningToResize: function() {
            $(window).off('resize', this._resizeHandler);
            this._resizeHandler = null;
        },

        /**
         * Prepare to switching the background image
         */
        _prepareSwitching: function() {
            this.$bg.css('backgroundImage', this.imageList.url(this.index));
        }
    });

    /**
     * Data Keys
     * @type {Object}
     */
    BgSwitcher.keys = {
        instance: 'bgSwitcher'
    };

    /**
     * Default Config
     * @type {Object}
     */
    BgSwitcher.defaultConfig = {
        images: [],
        interval: 5000,
        start: true,
        loop: true,
        shuffle: false,
        effect: 'fade',
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'swing'
    };

    /**
     * Built-In switch handlers (effects)
     * @type {Object}
     */
    BgSwitcher.switchHandlers = {
        fade: function($el) {
            $el.animate({opacity: 0}, this.config.duration, this.config.easing);
        },

        blind: function($el) {
            $el.animate({height: 0}, this.config.duration, this.config.easing);
        },

        clip: function($el) {
            $el.animate({
                top: parseInt($el.css('top'), 10) + $el.height() / 2,
                height: 0
            }, this.config.duration, this.config.easing);
        },

        slide: function($el) {
            $el.animate({top: -$el.height()}, this.config.duration, this.config.easing);
        },

        drop: function($el) {
            $el.animate({
                left: -$el.width(),
                opacity: 0
            }, this.config.duration, this.config.easing);
        },

        hide: function($el) {
            $el.hide();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Define effect
     *
     * @param {String} name
     * @param {Function} fn
     */
    BgSwitcher.defineEffect = function(name, fn) {
        this.switchHandlers[name] = fn;
    };

    /**
     * BgSwitcher.ImageList
     *
     * @param {Array} images
     * @constructor
     */
    BgSwitcher.ImageList = function(images) {
        this.images = images;
        this.createImagesBySequence();
        this.preload();
    };

    $.extend(BgSwitcher.ImageList.prototype, {
        /**
         * Images is sequenceable
         *
         * @returns {boolean}
         */
        isSequenceable: function() {
            return typeof this.images[0] === 'string' &&
                typeof this.images[1] === 'number' &&
                typeof this.images[2] === 'number';
        },

        /**
         * Create an images by sequence
         */
        createImagesBySequence: function() {
            if (!this.isSequenceable()) {
                return;
            }

            var images = [],
                base = this.images[0],
                min = this.images[1],
                max = this.images[2];

            do {
                images.push(base.replace(/\.\w+$/, min + '$&'));
            } while (++min <= max);

            this.images = images;
        },

        /**
         * Preload an images
         */
        preload: function() {
            var path,
                length = this.images.length,
                i = 0;

            for (; i < length; i++) {
                path = this.images[i];
                if (!loadedImages[path]) {
                    loadedImages[path] = new Image();
                    loadedImages[path].src = path;
                }
            }
        },

        /**
         * Shuffle an images
         */
        shuffle: function() {
            var j, t,
                i = this.images.length,
                original = this.images.join();

            if (!i) {
                return;
            }

            while (i) {
                j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
                t = this.images[--i];
                this.images[i] = this.images[j];
                this.images[j] = t;
            }

            if (this.images.join() === original) {
                this.shuffle();
            }
        },

        /**
         * Get the image from index
         *
         * @param {number} index
         * @returns {string}
         */
        get: function(index) {
            return this.images[index];
        },

        /**
         * Get the URL with function of CSS
         *
         * @param {number} index
         * @returns {string}
         */
        url: function(index) {
            return 'url(' + this.get(index) + ')';
        },

        /**
         * Count of images
         *
         * @returns {number}
         */
        count: function() {
            return this.images.length;
        }
    });

    $.BgSwitcher = BgSwitcher;
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: They look the same to me in Chrome. Can you explain the problem further?

Comment: Looks like he just fixed it, it was there before and not now.

Comment: Yes i have the problem in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're adding the background image to one `<div>` and there's another `<div>` after it in the markup:

```
<div style='background-image...'>...</div>
<div id='wrapper'>...</div>
```

It looks like your JavaScript is trying to explicitly set the height of the first `<div>` to match the full page height, but it's calculating that height before the browser has had a chance to apply all the CSS rules, thus it's getting the wrong answer.

I'm not sure why you're using such a complex approach. It would be much easier to simply set the background image on the `<div>` that contains the content, or at least on a parent of that `<div>`

---

**Additional Updates**

One problem is that you're running your script on the `document.ready` event. That event fires when the browser has parsed the markup sufficiently to construct the DOM, but ***before*** it has applied any styles to that markup. That's one reason the calculated height isn't correct. (Though, as other commenters have pointed out, sometimes the browser *is* fast enough. It's not reliable though.)

The first step would be to switch from `document.ready` to `window.onload`. The load event fires after the browser has loaded all content, including style sheets and images. As long as your JavaScript isn't doing anything to modify the height, that change should be sufficient to allow the script to calculate the correct height for the background `<div>`. If, however, your JavaScript (including external libraries) is doing something that could change the height, you'll have to wait until that's complete as well.

> Having said that, though, the markup and approach is really pretty bad. If you've actually paid someone for this, I'd be looking to get my money back.

Comment: Hey Stephan, thx for your answer. my Problem i use a script what i don't programming. That is this -> jquery.bgswitcher.js I don't know how can i take the div in the wrap container. Can you help me?

Comment: I'll edit my response with some further suggestions. Of course, I'm always available for consulting for a fee ;^)